# Setting up Synaptics Touchpad Gestures in 2017

Tags: unity, touchpad, multi-touch, synaptics

I have a lenovo t450s and it has a synaptics touchpad. In windows there are lots of gestures supported. In ubuntu 17.04, the only ones working are two finger vertical scrolling and right-click with 2-finger click.

The gesture I use most and one I use most though is a three finger swipe up to spread the windows. I'm wondering how to do this in Ubuntu. What's the current best way to support gestures? I've seen a few articles, one mentioning touchegg and another mentioning a command-line x-org driver but both were written in 2012. Which one is the recommended one that will work and is best supported currently?

Thanks!

Comment: I have a similar model and have been looking for the answer to this question for around four hours now. If I don't post an answer to the question means I have not found it and gave up.